# Subquery returned more than 1 value. Not permitted when subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or used as an expression

Tags: sql, sql-server

Am am getting the following SQL Error and am unsure why?

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

I have narrowed the problem down to one select in my proc.

```
DECLARE @ApplicationName varchar(32)
,@Email varchar(128)
,@Password varchar(128)

SET @ApplicationName = 'PraxiProSite'
SET @Email = 'jn@gmail.com'
SET @Password = 'jn@gmail.com'

DECLARE @PracId int
   SET @PracId = 
   (
        SELECT 
            MU.PractitionerId 
        FROM 
            MembershipUser AS MU WITH(NOLOCK) 
            LEFT JOIN Practitioner AS Pr WITH(NOLOCK) ON Pr.PractitionerId = MU.PractitionerId 
            LEFT JOIN Person AS Pe WITH(NOLOCK) ON Pe.PersonId = Pr.PersonId
    )

SELECT @PracId
```

Comment: What's unclear about the error message?

Comment: `Select top 1` maybe?

Comment: It is becuase in SET @PracId  your are trying to set one value to the variable, but the query returns multiple.

Comment: The database is set up so it will never select more then one, ether null or one value, in this case its null

Comment: run the query inside directly and you'll see that it's returning multiple values. The error is saying to you, "Which of these values am I supposed to use? I was expecting only a single value!"

Comment: I am not sure the left joins add anything to your query, since you are only selecting from the main table. is there a missing where clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've forgotten to include the filter, e.g. :

```
SELECT 
  MU.PractitionerId 
FROM MembershipUser AS MU WITH(NOLOCK) 
LEFT JOIN Practitioner AS Pr WITH(NOLOCK) 
  ON Pr.PractitionerId = MU.PractitionerId 
LEFT JOIN Person AS Pe WITH(NOLOCK) ON Pe.PersonId = Pr.PersonId
WHERE MU.Email = @Email and /* whatever else you need */
```

However, this is still most likely not the best way to do this. You're using ASP.NET membership, right? There's a bunch of stored procedures you should use to get the user ID (otherwise you're going to have trouble comparing the password, I expect), and do the rest in your SQL.

Answer (score 3):

```
SET @PracId = 
   (
        SELECT Top 1
            MU.PractitionerId 
        FROM 
            MembershipUser AS MU WITH(NOLOCK) 
            LEFT JOIN Practitioner AS Pr WITH(NOLOCK) ON Pr.PractitionerId = MU.PractitionerId 
            LEFT JOIN Person AS Pe WITH(NOLOCK) ON Pe.PersonId = Pr.PersonId
    )
```

Make sure you do the order by here, to get the expected value

Comment: This returned 1 if nothing was found?

Comment: @Pomster: This always return one `MU.PractitionerId` when there is more than one value. Which is in your case, since you don't have a `where` condition. This will definitely returning more than once since you joining with two other tables as well

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can do it without a sub-query.

```
SELECT Top(1) @PracId = MU.PractitionerId 
FROM MembershipUser AS MU WITH(NOLOCK) 
        LEFT JOIN Practitioner AS Pr WITH(NOLOCK) ON Pr.PractitionerId = MU.PractitionerId 
        LEFT JOIN Person AS Pe WITH(NOLOCK) ON Pe.PersonId = Pr.PersonId
```

And if your final query is `SELECT @PracId`, you may not need the variable as well.

```
SELECT TOP(1) MU.PractitionerId 
FROM MembershipUser AS MU WITH(NOLOCK) 
        LEFT JOIN Practitioner AS Pr WITH(NOLOCK) ON Pr.PractitionerId = MU.PractitionerId 
        LEFT JOIN Person AS Pe WITH(NOLOCK) ON Pe.PersonId = Pr.PersonId
```

Comment: Hey, what is the difference with this one? is it performing well compare to the way OP tried? I know this is easy way when we setting up multiple parameters from one query !!

Comment: @Kaf, thanks this has worked. I had to remove top(1) but then it worked.

Comment: If you need to select all rows, yes you don't need `TOP (1)`

Comment: The database is set up so that it will ether select one values as there can only be one or null. Then i use that value as a check to run an option of other proc's dependent if a value was found or not.

Comment: In that case you could use `IF EXISTS(Your Query..)` to check the existence of records and do the rest.

Answer (score 1):

I believe also you maybe missing a WHERE clause in the SELECT statement.  Because you are currently select all the rows from MembershipUser

```
SET @PracId = 
(
    SELECT Top 1
        MU.PractitionerId 
    FROM 
        MembershipUser AS MU WITH(NOLOCK) 
        LEFT JOIN Practitioner AS Pr WITH(NOLOCK) ON Pr.PractitionerId = MU.PractitionerId 
        LEFT JOIN Person AS Pe WITH(NOLOCK) ON Pe.PersonId = Pr.PersonId
    WHERE .....
   (i.e. WHERE MU.email = @email
           AND MU.Application = @application)
)
```